# file name attribute from blobinfo in google app engine using java

Tags: google-app-engine

I have stored the file as `blob` in app engine using java. the `blobInfo` displays all the details.i have already displayed using the following code:

```
 BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
 Iterator<BlobInfo> blobInfos = blobInfoFactory.queryBlobInfos();
```

Now how to retrieve the file name attribute alone in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `blobKey`, then the simplest would be :

```
BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey)
String blobFilename = blobInfo.getFilename();
```

Comment: You get the `blobKey` when you save a file into blobstore. You should save into datastore - where depends on your biz logic (mostly associated with user that uploaded it).